# Passing Form Variables Between If Statement

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, if-statement

I'm working on a front end submission page for Wordpress that works in a number of steps.

So I've got a form on a page and it's gathering data over a few stages and posting it after each stage.

I can do this fine using GET, but I don't want the variables viewable in the URL because it would be easy for people to edit other posts on the blog which they did not write.

How would I go about passing the post ID from stage to stage using this method?
Is there a better method out there for multiple page forms?

As you can see below, I need to pass the post ID between the setup step and step one somehow but I dont want it to be in the URL as a GET.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so it seems that the step to confirm the the stage is completed in the if else statement was where I was loosing all the POST and SESSION variables, I have now changed it so that it displays a form with hidden inputs instead of a continue link for the GET request. Updated Pastebin - http://pastebin.com/LpHrHwrE

Here is the code I am using: http://pastebin.com/8b4qMNrm

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['step'])){
    $step = $_GET['step'];

    if ($step == "setup"){
     $setup = ""; $step_one ="";
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $guide_title = trim($_POST['guide_title']);
            if($guide_title != "" ){
                $post = array(
                  'post_title'     => $guide_title,
                );  

                $post_ID = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
                $stage_complete = true;
            } else {
                $message = "Please complete all required fields.";
            }   
        } else {
            $guide_title = "";
            $stage_complete = false;
        }

    } else if($step == "one"){
    $setup ="c"; $step_one = "";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $guide_new_title = trim($_POST['guide_new_title']);

            if($guide_new_title != ""){
                $my_post = array();
                $my_post['ID'] = $guide_id;
                $my_post['post_title'] = $guide_new_title;

                wp_update_post( $my_post );

                $stage_complete = true;
            } else {
                $message = "Please complete all required fields.";
            }   
        } else {
            $guide_title = "";
            $stage_complete = false;
        }
    }
} else {
    $step = "start";
}

if(empty($message)){
    $message = "";
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
    <?php if($step == "start"){ ?>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink() ?>?step=setup" method="POST" class="formee">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go To Post Setup">
    </form>
    <?php } else if($step == "setup"){ ?>
    <?php echo $message; if($stage_complete == false){ ?>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?step=setup" method="POST" class="formee">
    <label>Guide Title <em class="formee-req">*</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="guide_title" required="required" value="<?php echo htmlentities($guide_title); ?>">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Setup Post">
    </form>
    <?php } else { $step_one = "c" ?>
    <p>Post Has Been Setup.</p>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?step=one" class="button">Continue To Step One &rarr;</a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } else if($step == "one"){ ?>
    <?php echo $message; if($stage_complete == false){ ?>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?step=one" method="POST" class="formee">
    <label>Guide Title <em class="formee-req">*</em></label>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Rename Post Title">
    </form>
    <?php } else { $step_one = "c" ?>
    <p>Post Has Been Renamed.</p>
    <a href="index.php?step=finish" class="button">Finished &rarr;</a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a hidden field in your form like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="postID" value="<?= $theID ?>" />
```

And then use `POST` rather than `GET` for the form.

Alternatively you could use a session variable:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['postID'] = $theID;

// Access via $_SESSION['postID']
```

Comment: I have tried using the hidden fields but it doesn't seem to pass it through properly leaving empty post fields and when I try using session it gives an error - Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent.

Comment: Make sure `session_start()` comes before you output anything, try it right at the top of each file you use it.

Comment: If for any reason hidden fields are not an option, $_SESSION is the way to go. This should be an accepted answer.